# How to remove duplicate files from the Photos app library

Tags: macos, photos.app

I am running OSX 10.12.6 and sorting a large number of mostly not native digital pictures (scans from negatives).
Using the command:

```
fdupes -r -A  "/Users/yves/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/Masters"
```

I get many results of duplicates like below, same files but in different subfolders:

```
/Users/yves/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/Masters/2019/12/27/20191227-174527/_NIK3130.tif
/Users/yves/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/Masters/2019/12/31/20191231-081818/_NIK3130.tif
/Users/yves/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/Masters/2020/01/02/20200102-183407/_NIK3130.tif
```

1. Is this normal behavior ? I understand the same files may have been imported several times, but I wonder:
2. is is safe to eliminate the duplicates and how best to do it ? For convenience I am using exiftool in combination with Applescript to adjust (reconstruct mostly)  picture metadata in the Photos library from selected pictures and want to make sure I do this only once and for the correct file.

Comment: This looks as if you've imported the same picture three times: on Dec 27th, Dec 31st and Jan 2nd.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=finding+duplicate+photos for some posts about how best to handle duplicate pictures within Photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't come up in Photos.app, I wouldn't touch what goes inside .photolibrary package. There are just too many questions of Photo library going wild. You anyway won't be saving much space there, if the files are tiny.

- [What software can find close duplicates from 2TB worth of pictures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76302/what-software-can-find-close-duplicates-from-2tb-worth-of-pictures)

Comment: TIFFs usually aren't tiny :-) But I agree, removing duplicates directly within the package isn't a good idea.

Comment: depends on what made them ;p If Autodesk sketchbook, not more than 2 MB.